# add create 'All' option in drop down button in html

Tags: html

[HTML]

Now that I have three options in the drop down button:

```
 <select id='campus' class="form-control">
     <option value="Z010">Campus1</option>
     <option value="Z020">Campus2</option>
     <option value="Z040" selected>Campus3</option>
     <option value="?????">- All Campuses-</option>
 </select>
```

Now that i want to add a choice of "All Campus" in the drop down menu, which includes all students from all campus, what should i do ?

I can not do the following because i need "AND" within the bracket, not "OR":

```
<option value="{'Z010', 'Z020', 'Z040'}">All</option>
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: How do you plan on using the value? In PHP, JavaScript, or something else?

Comment: Javascript it is. Thanks

Comment: But how do you plan on using the value?

Comment: There is column in the sql database that contains campus code: Z010, Z020, Z040. And i'm trying sort by this column without adding a new campus code like Z070 which means all campus....Does that answer your questions?

Comment: Yes, but are you looking to store its value via AJAX, or access data via AJAX based on this?

Comment: Sorry, you need to add more information about how the value should be used to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach, using a `<select multiple>` and a few lines of javascript:

```js
var campusOptions = document.getElementsByTagName('option');
var allCampuses = document.querySelector('[value="all-campuses"]');

function selectAllCampuses() {
    if (allCampuses.selected === true) {
        for (var i = 0; i < (campusOptions.length - 1); i++) {
            campusOptions[i].selected = true;
            allCampuses.selected = false;
        }
    }
}

allCampuses.addEventListener('click', selectAllCampuses, false);
```

```html
<select id="campus" class="form-control" multiple>
     <option value="Z010">Campus1</option>
     <option value="Z020">Campus2</option>
     <option value="Z040" selected>Campus3</option>
     <option value="all-campuses">- All Campuses -</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: You can either link to an external .js file or - the simplest way - sandwich the code between `<script>` and `</script>` and then put all of it at the very end of the `html` document, just before `</body>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer man, it's really helpful. I try to upvote but i'm less than 15 reputations..

Comment: can i make that in a drop down list instead of a box? thanks!!

Comment: This is a `<select multiple>` - it's the equivalent of a drop-down list for situations where multiple options need to be available for selection.